# JUnit for JSF2.0 composite components

Tags: unit-testing, jsf, jsf-2

We are starting to build infrastructure components in JSF2.0.

What is the best approach for unit testing them?

I tried `JSFUnit` in the past but wasn't satisfied with it. Is there an easier way to implement it?

Comment: What do you wish to test in the composite components? The HTML rendered or the evaluation of EL expressions, or the updates against the model? Btw, JSFUnit now uses Arquillian and not Castor, so it might be worth revisiting it, for Arquillian allows for Junit 4 tests to be written.

Answer (score 1):

This may be more integration testing than unit testing, but if you want to see how your components work in an actual browser, the selenium project has some nice features, and you can do it all through unit tests.  You can look it over here: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html.  I've found that between regular unit tests, unit tests using jmockit or the like, and selenium, I can cover pretty much everything when testing my components.

Cheers,

Bill